# Multithreading - Waiting for threads

Tags: vb.net, windows, multithreading

Coding in Visual Basic 2012 (Vb.Net)

I have a application where the program, deletes files, moves files, extracts files, and etc. (It's some what an installer)

So I am pretty "newbie" at Vb.net, and yesterday I decided to learn something about Multithreading.

I went ahead and added 7 threads, for 7 different tasks the program has to do.

When I was fully done, I noticed a problem, the threads are doing their tasks at the same exact time.

Which is something very critical in the installer, it has to do all the file moving, deleting, and etc in a very specific order.

I read on MDSN and other websites how to make a thread wait for another thread to finish, before running.

> Thread1.Join()

I also tried the "Join" thingy... But looks like it only makes the thread wait for the UI thread, not for the previous thread that was launched.

So... I was unsuccessful. Can someone please help me out? Or point me to the right direction.

A little code sample:

```
    Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DeleteTemp)
    Thread1.Start()

    Dim Thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf CleanMods)
    Thread2.Start()
    Thread2.Join()

    Dim Thread3 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MoveZip)
    Thread3.Start()
    Thread3.Join()

    Dim Thread4 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyExtract)
    Thread4.Start()
    Thread4.Join()

    Dim Thread5 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf CreateDirs)
    Thread5.Start()
    Thread5.Join()

    Dim Thread6 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf InstallMods)
    Thread6.Start()
    Thread6.Join()        

    Dim Thread7 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DeleteTemp)
    Thread7.Start()
    Thread7.Join()

    Finish.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Finish.Show()
    Me.Hide()
```

BackgroundWorkder Example:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    DeleteTemp()
    CleanMods()
    MoveZip()
    MyExtract()
    CreateDirs()
    InstallMods()
    DeleteTemp()
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using the TPL (`Task` and `Await`)

Comment: share some code please.. but in general, seems like you need only one thread, beyond the UI thread. And +1 for `async await` if plenty of IO is involved..

Comment: I will update the thread with some code right now!

Comment: @VikasGupta I tried it with one thread... But the UI still freezes, that is why I decided to do more than 1.

Comment: @SLaks Can you please give me an example with TPL? That would help a newbie like me ;)

Comment: @dimabal10000 Launch your UI normally. You should **not** call `Thread.Join` in UI thread. Rest of the details seem too broad to cover in one question :(. Also consider using `BackgroundWorker` class in .Net framework. Use only one instance, (as per your requirement, serially do your install steps). It is designed for scenarios like this, and there will be much less explaining to do.

Comment: @VikasGupta Regarding the backgroundworker... I don't know why, but I just can't get it to work. It seems like it runs all the codes at the same time, and not in an order.

Comment: @dimabal10000 Please look on net / SO for usage of `BackgroundWorker`. Post a separate question if you still can't resolve the issue. BackgroundWorker is supposed to run on one thread.. so I can't think of a reason why it would do 7 things at once / in parallel, unless you created 7 different instances of it. If it wasn't clear before, once again, please use only one instance of `BackgroundWorker` to execute the 7 steps of your installer.

Comment: @VikasGupta I might haven't been clear enough... Technically what it does is hurries. Just like the multithreading problem I had earlier. I want it to do all the codes one by one. But it decides to go to next line of code before fully finishing the other. Example: You press "download" it starts downloading a file, and instead of waiting to complete the download, it will proceed to moving files.

Comment: @dimabal10000 can't move the conversation to chat, because your rep is not enough.. Anyway.. please post the code you stated as example in your last comment.

Comment: @VikasGupta I updated the thread... Here is what I mean: It would install the files (move them to the correct directories), before finish the file extraction. Annd... How in the world is the program supposed to move files that don't exist (yet). This is what I hate backgroundworker for. I tried to Google for a solution... But never found anything related to this topic, when it came to backgroundworker.

Comment: If I find a solution... I will post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using TPL in C#. Declare an array to store the tasks then kick off each task with the Run() method. Pass the task array to the WaitAll() or you could use WaitAny() to handle each task as they complete.

```
Task[] theTasks = new Task[7];

theTasks[0] = Task.Run( () => Console.WriteLine("Do Stuff"));

Task.WaitAll(theTasks);
```

A link to the TPL documentation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.DoWork

        DeleteTemp()

        MoveZip()

        MyExtract()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        CreateDirs()

        CleanMods()

        InstallMods()

        DeleteTemp()

        Finish.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Finish.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

So basically I moved all the codes that are used by the UI thread into my RunWorkerCompleted.. Which made my UI thread freeze for around 5 - 10 seconds... But I don't think it's a big deal :)